# Existing Ubuntu doesn't boot after installation try

Tags: boot, uefi

I use Ubuntu 18.04 on a 500GB M.2 drive and I got a new 1TB M.2 recently, I wanted to install new Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop to new drive. So therefore I downloaded **ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso** and made an external 512GB SSD bootable with **mkusb** and then replaced the old drive with new one.

I booted from external **SATA** and live-ubuntu run. I started the installation, but it gave me an error. It said `Intel RTS(RAID) must be deactivated in BIOS`. I deactivated it and selected **AHCI**, tried again, but it didn't install.

I then replaced the drive again to use old Ubuntu 18. I also reactivated Intel RTS(RAID) because the old drive was using it. But when I try to boot, there are only 4 lines with the following error on the screen:

```
Failed to open EFI\boot\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image EFI\boot\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start MokManeger: Not Found 
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Not Found
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: 1. Which Ubuntu are you trying to install (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop or Server, or some other iso file)? 2. Ubuntu wants AHCI on the drives (not RST). When you deactivated RST, did you select AHCI? 3. What error did you get? It you can't remember, please try again (with 20.04.3) and edit your original question to show the error output, actually any relevant observation of what happened.

Comment: In order to know details about your computer, please [download and run the `system-info` script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/). Let it upload the result to a pastebin and paste the link into a new comment here. It will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for those details. 1. Did you make a live (live-only) drive with mkusb, or did you make a persistent live drive? 2. Did you try to use the whole internal drive (and overwrite whatever was there before? -- I suggest that you use AHCI mode, otherwise I think there will be problems with Ubuntu. And I suggest again that you try with 20.04.3 and check what errrors you get (should be different compared to what you got with 18.04 LTS and RST). You can also use gparted and create a fresh GPT partition table (remove whatever is already on the new drive, that might disturb booting).